# Include URL in a d3.js JSON JavaScript SVG

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

Am working with the following `d3.js` on [GitHub](http://bl.ocks.org/fabiovalse/d784198bdc1c76221393).

Currently, you open the tree by clicking the blue circle. For example, when the blue circle for `Agent` is clicked, the tree opens to `Organisation` and `Person`.

Woulds like to make a term in the tree a URL. For example, on mouseover the term `Agent` would reveal a URL and - when clicked - would open the URL.

Continuing the above example, `Agent` would open to [Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent) on Wikipedia.

Working with the JSON file:

```
http://wafi.iit.cnr.it/webvis/tmp/dbpedia/realOntology.json
```

I code a term with a URL as follows:

```
"<a href=\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent\">Agent<\/a>"
```

but cannot bind the `href` string to a term.

**How to bind a URL to a term in a `d3.js` + `JSON` structure?**

Comment: Links in SVG are made with a modified href attribute: `<a xlink:href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><text>example</text></a>`

Comment: @Imperative Following your example, does a quote and closing slash need to be escaped? If I take your string as-is, the `JS` fails.

Comment: @Imperative. I added the escape for a quote and closing slash. The `JS` works, but the label is the entire string, not the >term< in <text>example</text>.